# Simple inner join not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query the sum of the populations of all cities where the CONTINENT is 'Asia'.
The two tables CITY and COUNTRY are as follows,

```
city - id, countrycode, name population
country - code, name, continent, population
```

Here's my query

```
SELECT SUM(POPULATION) FROM COUNTRY CITY
JOIN ON COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE CONTINENT = "Asia";
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong. I'm new to SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't working because the way you've written it `CITY` is being interpreted as a table alias for `COUNTRY`. Additionally, it looks like you've got a POPULATION column in each table so you need to disambiguate it. Let me rewrite the query for you:

```
SELECT SUM(CITY.POPULATION)
FROM COUNTRY
JOIN CITY
ON COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE COUNTRY.CONTINENT = "Asia";
```

Comment: Also "Asia" didn't work, 'Asia' worked any idea why. I'm new to SQL. Both are VARCHAR2

Comment: Hmm. Both single and double quotes work for me in MySQL. Are you using something other than MySQL?

Comment: Nope it's a web based MySQL compiler

Comment: What version of MySQL? You can run `SELECT version();` to find out. I tested in version 5.6.22.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was already answered, but I would like to put out the optimised solution. The below solution will decrease the execution time and at the same time it will take less resource to perform the SQL query.

```
select sum(a.population) from city a
inner join(select * from country where continent = 'Asia') b
on a.countrycode=b.code;
```

I would like to explain a bit on top of that, as you see I'm applying the filter condition before performing Join operation. So during reshuffling phase, the data would be very less and this way query will take less time to execute. You will not see a drastic performance changes in less data size, however while running this queries in large dataset, you can see the performance improvement.

Answer (score 2):

The JOIN needs to go between the two table names:

```
SELECT SUM(CITY.POPULATION) FROM COUNTRY INNER JOIN CITY
ON COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE CONTINENT = "Asia";
```

Comment: I get the following error of running this `SELECT SUM(POPULATION) 
* 
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined `

Comment: @Zeus See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36636048/166339) which resolves that error message.

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL JOIN syntax manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT SUM(COUNTRY.POPULATION) 
FROM COUNTRY
JOIN CITY
ON COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE
WHERE CONTINENT = "Asia";
```

Comment: When I run this, the error message I get is, `SELECT SUM(POPULATION) 
* 
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined `

Comment: @Zeus See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36636048/166339) which resolves that error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(CITY.POPULATION) 
FROM CITY          
INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON  CITY.COUNTRYCODE = COUNTRY.Code 
where COUNTRY.CONTINENT = 'Asia';
```

Line 3 has `INNER JOIN` because there is one column in both the tables that are common to both

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(city.population) FROM city LEFT JOIN country ON city.countrycode=country.code
WHERE country.continent='Asia'
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code using Oracle.

```
SELECT SUM(c.POPULATION)
FROM CITY c
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY co  ON c.CountryCode = co.Code
     WHERE CONTINENT ='Asia' ;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

select SUM(cty.POPULATION) from COUNTRY cntry, CITY cty where cty.COUNTRYCODE=cntry.CODE AND cntry.CONTINENT='Asia';

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please check out the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to improve your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(S.Population)
from City S
where S.CountryCode in (select Code
                       from Country C
                       where CONTINENT = 'Asia');
```